# What difference does it make whether the computer uses USB Ethernet Adapter, or a network card?

Tags: usb, ethernet, adapter

Just what the title states.

I'd like to know what difference it makes to the modem/switch, speed, power consumption whether the computer is connected by a USB Ethernet Adapter instead of a physical network card installed into a PCI slot.

As a corollary, it would be nice to know which you would recommend to a nouveau at networking.

Comment: Some report problems when gaming with usb ethernet, a card on the motherboard will outperform a usb adapter under these situations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Computer technician weighing in here...

Just as the other posters have said, your best bet is an internal network card. This is for the following reasons:

1. USB IO is controlled by the CPU and USB network cards may or may not use [DMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access)--this means CPU usage could grow with network traffic;
2. The USB bus is shared, which means one thirsty peripheral can (in a severe case) impact the performance of other peripherals such as hard drives and may affect the latency of HID peripherals such as mice and keyboards;
3. There are very few ethernet chipsets and they all have solid, tested drivers which are used directly to support PCI cards--when the USB interface is added, an additional driver is necessary to "glue" the chipset to the USB bus;

   - Drivers are easy to mess up, particularly when small companies are involved.

In theory, systemic power usage would be greater for a USB adapter because of the additional CPU overhead that cannot be off-loaded to a dedicated chip. This may not be the case for high-throughput cases, though (read: I am really just making an educated guess).

Comment: Just to clarify - should #1 be: USB IO is controlled by the CPU and **USB** network cards cannot use DMA

Comment: You're right! I've changed my post.

Comment: +1 on the above, but note that many PCs have two or more USB buses, so not all peripherals share the same bus.

Comment: They share the same CPU though. Multiple cores nonwithstanding...

Comment: What I was trying to say... but you did it much better!

Comment: What makes you think USB cannot use DMA?  USB host controllers can certainly use DMA.  There's nothing to stop the Ethernet MAC from using DMA to its local memory.

Answer (score 3):

I would always recommend a dedicated card/adapter over anything USB whenever it is practical.

USB is good for convenience, but should never be used for critical components where it can be helped.

I do not have any figures regarding power or speed.

That being said, I am sure it "can" support full 100Meg networking speed - I am not entirely sure and would doubt about gigabit speed.

If you go back a few years to when many ISPs gave USB networking, they were always causing problems. The most common is that when the CPU is being used intensively (e.g. above 80%), it wasn't uncommon to see packet loss and other errors.

Comment: There are gigabit USB adapters.

Comment: Unless it's USB 3.0 I can guarantee you that GbE USB adapters aren't running at 1000Mbit/sec when USB 2.0 bandwidth limit is 480Mbit/sec.  Still would benefit from GbE jumbo frames though.

Answer (score 1):

A USB Ethernet adapter IS a network "card". They are the same for all intents and purposes. I am not sure which takes more power, a PCI slot or USB, but it is negligible considering the DC voltages that used internally.

I still prefer an internal network card, but only because I don't like things handing off my computer, if at all possible. And such things can break off.

Comment: @KCoutreau Power usage has nothing to do with the internal DC voltages. For instance, the iPad will pull more power from a USB port than almost any other device, even though the port never goes above 5V. (To get increased power, the device increases the amperage.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered but the top voted answer was not good enough and I do need to point out the fact that PCIe bus lanes also goes through the CPU directly as well or they can go through the chipset's lanes which then goes to the CPU eventually as well depending on their architecture layouts... And this was answered when USB network card were still using even worse controllers than realtek controllers which some actually needed weird drivers since they are not using realtek nor intel based network controllers.... so this is to correct a misconception of yesteryear's top voted answer about lanes and to update on the 10 years later situation...

So to answer your question, TBH it depends... on the network card's controller not what interface you used whether its a gigabit to USB 3.0 or a gigabit PCIe card... as what the network card's controller send to the chipset and CPU is still the same data stream of 0 and 1.... its just how fast can the controller on the network card can decode the analog electrical signal to digital 0s and 1s and send it to the lanes and finally into the CPU...

This is where most USB ethernet adapters loses out to PCIe since most of them use cheaper controllers to control their compact sized single slot network card while those on the PCIe cards use slightly better controllers for things like multiple ethernet slots... but it is not the case all the time...

So unless you are 100% sure you are using an intel NIC network card, then even a USB ethernet adaptor is probably good enough for you... because if you are comparing a modern USB 3.0 ethernet adapter to a realtek controller network card, then the USB 3.0 ethernet adapter is probably going to win anyways most of the time...

Nowadays newer USB peripherals are using much better network controllers thanks to things like the nintendo switch and those portable console size computers like the steam deck... so any realtek controller really need to be thrown into a fire pit right now... since even a modern USB 3.0 network adapter is actually probably much better than a realtek controller powered network card from just a few years back....