# USB-C Ethernet adapter overhead

Tags: networking, usb, thunderbolt

[I'm aware of the overheads caused by using USB network adapters as opposed to 'proper' add-in cards - for example, the points raised in this QA from 2011](https://superuser.com/questions/294017/what-difference-does-it-make-whether-the-computer-uses-usb-ethernet-adapter-or).

Are things different with USB-C with USB 3.1? I note that for TB3 Apple does not sell a *Thunderbolt* ethernet adapter, instead it's a USB-C adapter. I know it's not a Thunderbolt adapter because Apple sells it for its compatibility with the 1-port, non-Thunderbolt, MacBook - but will using it have the same level of overhead as a traditional USB network adapter, or does its use of USB 3.1 mean it places less demand on host CPU power? Does USB 3.1 have any equivalent of DMA, for example?

Comment: No difference.  There's still the USB protocol overhead.  BTW The USB host controller (for any USB version) does use DMA, despite what the other answer claims.  It's illogical to think that a modern, high-speed peripheral controller would not be capable of DMA and require PIO.  Even UARTS can use DMA.

Comment: there is now a TB3 "Adapter" which offers you 2 10GBit ports, but this is a heavy peace of hardware, which is hard to carry with you around: http://www.sonnettech.com/product/twin10g-thunderbolt3.html

Answer (score 1):

The article you referred to is 5 years old. At that time there were no USB3 network adapter chips, so everything did go over USB2 data rate, and 40 MBytes/s (plus some idiocies of COM class protocol) did contribute to reduced performance of NIC over USB, as compared to PCI bandwidth and real interrupt structure. As result, USB2 cannot drive the gigabit protocol to full level of performance.

With advent of USB3, there are USB3 NIC dongles, which do not have the limitation of USB2 data rate, and there is almost no overhead due to USB serial protocol.

With the advent of Type-C connector nothing has changed. Although the Type-C connector was introduced formally as a part of USB3.1 specifications, Type-C can mean 480Mbps (High-Speed) data rate, or SuperSpeed 5Gbps rate (Gen.1), or 10Mbps (Gen.2) data rate. So conformance to USB3.1 and Type-C does not mean much without technical clarification. AFAIK, there is no USB3.1 Gen2 controller chips yet on the market of NIC dongles, so the question about performance of Gen2 protocol in network applications is too early to consider.

And yes, for the last 14 years since publication of Intel Enhanced Host Controller Interface (EHCI) specifications (2002), USB transactions in all computers use DMA (bus mastering) exclusively. By design, the EHCI hardware is essentially an almost autonomous processor of linked lists in DMA mode. USB 3.0/3.1 host controllers do the same, but under more efficient control.

So, things are different as compared to 5-year-old technology, but Type-C, being a connector specifications for a variety of serial interfaces (USB3, Thunderbolt, HDMI) does not change anything, unless Gen.2 speeds will be deployed sometime, and the 10Gbps Ethernet might become economically feasible.